# $("body").scrollTop() doesn't update in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a website:

http://beta.projektopia.se/

the body has several background-images that are updated on scroll like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).scroll(function(){
        var scrollfactor=$("body").scrollTop()*0.2;
        var centerscrollpos =scrollfactor+613;
        var docheight = $(document).height();
        var windowheight = $(window).height();
        var bottompos = (docheight-980)-((docheight-windowheight)*0.2)+scrollfactor;
        var scrollpos = 'center '+scrollfactor+'px,center '+bottompos+'px, center '+ centerscrollpos+'px,center 0px';
        $("body").css("background-position", scrollpos);
    });
});
```

Lots of calculations, but the important thing is that a scrollpos is created that should change the position of the background when you scroll, to create a parallax-effect. It works great in chrome, but in firefox, the variable scrollfactor, that is suppose to get the current scroll-position, doesn't update.

ps, some people have this issue due to lack of correct doctype. I believe i have declared it correctly like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scrollTop` jQuery method [has been known to be problematic](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/).

Depending on the browser, you may need to use `$('html, body').scrollTop()` or `$(document).scrollTop()` or `$(window).scrollTop()`.

Comment: The complaints in [the comments of your link](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) are 2 to 3 years old.  I have not had any trouble using `scrollTop` cross-browser.

Comment: Well, I have, as recently as three months ago. `'html, body'` seems to work best for me.

Comment: hrm, document and window works in chrome + firefox, any guesse what works in IE? ^^

Comment: `$(document).scrollTop()` is working for me in Chrome 32 (and all other modern browsers)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was any kind of `overflow` property on `html` element.
The moment I removed it, my `.scrollTop()` started working as it should.
I still wanted global `overflow-x: hidden` property on my page, so I just set it on `body` element.