# Jquery click event to target anchor not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, onclick, position, targeting

I have a navigation menu that is targeting anchors that are positioned by the data-position attribute within a page. I'm using this code snippet to make this work, and it works great in Safari and Chrome, but isn't working at all in Firefox. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance for any assistance you can offer!

```
$(document).on('click','.navigation a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $target = $( $(this).attr('href') );
    var position = $target.data('position');
    $('body').scrollTop( position * scrollHeight );
});
```

Comment: can you post your html too

Comment: Where are you defining scrollHeight? Are you trying to get $(document).scrollTop(), or the links position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your selector to

```
$('html, body')
```

Firefox overflow is applied at the `html` level by default. So your line of code would be

```
$('html, body').scrollTop( position * scrollHeight );
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149155/animate-scrolltop-not-working-in-firefox) might help you as well.

Comment: Any insight as to how I can animate the scrolling between links? To make the scrolling slower? Here's a link to my test page for reference: http://intercross.com/newsitebuild/index-final.html

Comment: `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: position * scrollHeight}, 'slow');`

Comment: is it possible to have each targeted div have 0 opacity until scrolled to their respective data-position where they would then be at 100%? thank you for your help

Comment: I would recommend starting a new question for that.

Comment: hmm... I don't have Safari 6 to test on, but it is working fine in Safari 5. Safari overflow is applied to the `body` level not the `html` level so this should work. Maybe this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219640/body-scrolltop-doesnt-update-in-safari) might help. Don't know what to say sorry :(