# scrollTop working fine in chrome but not in safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

Any help would be appreciated, I have tried almost everything available on web to get the current scroll value in safari browser but its always returning 0. No matter if I select body, document, html, documentElement etc.

Please suggestions. Below is the original line which is working fine in chrome.

```
$('body').scrollTop();
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219640/body-scrolltop-doesnt-update-in-safari

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$("body").scrollTop() doesn't update in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219640/body-scrolltop-doesnt-update-in-safari)